# Retriving the image from DB to imageView

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

There is the table in DB with images. I want, that an Image will show in Image View, but something is wrong and I have SQLException.

```
 ConnectionHelper ch=new ConnectionHelper();
    ch.Connect();
    String q="SELECT IMG FROM img_ins";

    Statement st=ch.con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(q);

   InputStream is= rs.getBinaryStream("IMG");
    OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(new File("img.jpg"));
    byte [] content= new byte[1024];
    int size=0;


        while ((size=is.read(content))!=-1){

            os.write(content, 0, size);
        }

    os.close();
    is.close();

    javafx.scene.image.Image image1=new Image("file:img.jpg", image.getFitWidth(), image.getFitHeight(), true, true);
    image.setImage(image1);
    image.setPreserveRatio(true);
}
```

Comment: Post the complete stack trace in the question.

Comment: Why are you writing to a file when you can [create an Image directly from an InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.io.InputStream-double-double-boolean-boolean-)?

Comment: First: adding images directly to database is not a good way. Second: read it as blob

Comment: What info your table contain? the image name or image directory ...etc?

Comment: @kodmanyagha Sorry, i'm new in this field.. can you explain a better way to add images? I tried to read it as blob.. but I didn't received a good result too..

Comment: @Yahya my table contains images with blob type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for `ResultSet` (my emphasis):

> A `ResultSet` object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. **Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row.** The next method moves the cursor to the next row

So you need to call `next()` to point the cursor to each row. Assuming there's at most one row in the table, or that you are only interested in the first row, you could do

```
ConnectionHelper ch=new ConnectionHelper();
ch.Connect();
String q="SELECT IMG FROM img_ins";

Statement st=ch.con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(q);

if (rs.next()) {
    InputStream is= rs.getBinaryStream("IMG");

    // instead of the next 9 lines, you could just do
    // javafx.scene.image.Image image1 = new Image(is);

    OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(new File("img.jpg"));
    byte [] content= new byte[1024];
    int size=0;


        while ((size=is.read(content))!=-1){

            os.write(content, 0, size);
        }

    os.close();
    is.close();

    javafx.scene.image.Image image1=new Image("file:img.jpg", image.getFitWidth(), image.getFitHeight(), true, true);
    image.setImage(image1);
    image.setPreserveRatio(true);
}
```

But note the comments below the OP as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work ... I don't have any Exceptions now, but Image is not shown.

Comment: @Roshki That's a completely different question: you didn't post any code related to displaying the `ImageView`.

Comment: I use Scene Builder and I insert ImageView through "public ImageView image;"

Comment: @Roshki Again, this has nothing to do with the question you posted (which is about retrieving an image from a database, not displaying an image in the UI). Does it work if you hard code an image instead of loading from the database? If not, then you should post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from a piece of code I wrote. This is an sqlite db

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:contactFX.db");
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
             ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sqlTCNote)) 
        {
            while(rset.next())
            {                
                Company c1 = new Company();  
                c1.setID(Integer.toString(rset.getInt("company_id")));
                c1.setName(rset.getString("company_name"));
                .
                .
                .
                c1.setWebSiteAddress(rset.getString("website_address"));  

                //This part is important to you.
                InputStream input = rset.getBinaryStream("image");
                InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(input);                        
                if(inputReader.ready())
                {
                    File tempFile = new File("tempFile.jpg");

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    while(input.read(buffer) > 0){
                        fos.write(buffer);                        
                    }
                    Image image = new Image(tempFile.toURI().toURL().toString());
                    c1.setImage(image);//right here is where you want to set your imageView with the image.
                }     
                companyData.add(c1);
            }              
        }
        catch(SQLException | IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```